# Taking size of overflown content into account for positioning

Tags: html, css, overflow

Is there a CSS/HTML-only way to take into account the size of overflown content? Consider the example below:

```css
.outerZeroSize {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: visible visible;
}

.innerContent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}

.belowContent {
  
}
```

```html
<div class="outerZeroSize">
  <div class="innerContent">
    Some content<br/>
    Some more content <br/>
    And some more
  </div>
</div>
<div class="belowContent">Content below</div>
```

The text in the div `belowContent` ends up on top of the text of `innerContent`.

**Question:** Since the `height` of `innerContent` is `300px`, I would like `belowContent` to appear `300px` below `outerZeroSize` (instead of on top of it). Is this possible with CSS/HTML?

**Constraints:**

- Assume that `.outerZeroSize` and `.innerContent` cannot change (neither HTML, nor CSS part), because they come from a third-party ([React-Virtualized Table](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/Table.md)).
- **UPDATE:** The height of `.innerContent` can change dynamically, `300px` is just an example (so just offsetting `.belowContent` by this same amount is not an option, either).
- What can be changed is `.belowContent` (HTML and CSS), and of course it is possible to add stuff **around** the `.outerZeroSize` div.

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52785665/react-virtualized-table-to-grow-up-to-a-maximal-height) (from React Virtualized Table perspective).

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a **300px margin-top** to `belowContent`.

```css
.outerZeroSize {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: visible visible;
}

.innerContent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}

.belowContent {
  margin-top: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerZeroSize">
  <div class="innerContent">
    Some content<br/>
    Some more content <br/>
    And some more
  </div>
</div>
<div class="belowContent">Content below</div>
```

---

Another solution would be to move `belowContent` inside `outerZeroSize`.

```css
.outerZeroSize {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: visible visible;
}

.innerContent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}

.belowContent {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerZeroSize">
  <div class="innerContent">
    Some content<br/>
    Some more content <br/>
    And some more
  </div>
  <div class="belowContent">Content below</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Quentin: this is the right answer for the original question. However, I forgot to add an important detail: the `300px` height is not fixed, but varies dynamically (these are rows in a table). I'll update the question accordingly. (As per including it into `outerZeroSize`, that is not an option, as stated in the original question.)

Comment: It changes everything, indeed. Any chance you can override `outerZeroSize` styles in your CSS file?